# Facebook API - Friend List

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I searched the internet the whole day for this, and came to the conclusion that there is no way to get a user's full friend list since API 2.0 (correct me if I am wrong).
What I want to do is, given the app user and another facebook user, generate a report about their "second level" mutual friends. That is - (friends of mine) who are friends with (a friend of his). Illustration: [image]

Is this kind of thing possible after facebook's restriction since API 2.0 in any platform (Different SDKs, Facebook's Graph API, etc)?

Many Thanks.

Comment: No there is no way to get all friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-context/all_mutual_friends

There is no way to get friends (or users in general) who did not authorize your App. Every list you get will only include users who authorized your App.

Comment: So there is no way to retrieve a "second degree mutual friends" through any facebook api, what about 3rd party softwares? anything you can think of?

Comment: no, there is no way. not with any additional software either. that would be weird, considering the recent changes.